# props.callback is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am looking to trigger execution of a parent method from a child component.

```
const ParentComponent: FunctionComponent = () => {

 const [detailsOpenState, setDetailsOpenState] = React. useState('hidden');

 function myCallbackMethod() {
   setDetailsOpenState('displayed');
 }

 return (
     <TableBody>
        < ChildComponent callback = { myCallbackMethod } />
     </TableBody>
 );

}
```

My child component:

```
const ChildComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({irrelevantInterface}, props) => {
  
  function openDetails() {
    props.callback();
  }

  return (
  ...
  <TableRow onClick={openDetails}>
    
  </TableRow>
  ...
  )
}
```

I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: props.callback is not a function`

I have implemented it the way I found in every possible documentation. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

My Props look like this

```
interface Props  {
  irrelevantInterface: bla_blabla;
  callback: any; 
}
```

My callback function does not get passed from the parent component. Instead, I get an undefined object in `callback`. How do I say in this definition, that a parent's function is supposed to be called here?

Comment: Props are the *first* argument to a functional component.

Comment: Ok, I changed it, now i get this error: Property 'callback' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<Props>'

Comment: Well *does* `Props` include a definition of `callback`. We can't see it from what you've posted.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I am new to react. What kind of props definition are you talking about? What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: The *type*, `FunctionComponent<Props>` - what *is* Props? If you're expecting a prop named callback, it should be defined there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please read update.

Comment: You still have the same problem I pointed out in my first comment. If you've changed things and it still doesn't work then give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
const ChildComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({irrelevantInterface, callback}) => {
  
  function openDetails() {
    callback();
  }

  return (
  ...
  <TableRow onClick={openDetails}>
    
  </TableRow>
  ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error I get an error Property 'props' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<Props>'

Answer (score 1):

This part: `({irrelevantInterface}, props) =>` you are receiving 2 arguments from parent component. Always the first argument is props, you defined your first argument as `{irrelevantInterface}`. this is actually [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) your first argument and extracting `irrelevantInterface` from it. The second argument passed to your component, which you named `prop` is actually used for defining [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) in function component and this code mistakenly names it `props`.

So I believe what you are looking for is something like this: `const ChildComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {` or `const ChildComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({irrelevantInterface, ...props}) => {`

This way you can access `props.callback` with no problem.

Comment: I went with your second option.l I get an error Property 'props' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<Props>'

Comment: Well, I thought that `Props` in `<Props>`  was defined by yourself, if you haven't defined it, you need to define it. like : `const ChildComponent: FunctionComponent<{callback: () => void}> = (props) => {` for this to work

Comment: From your example it seems like you are passing a void function into callback, so nothing will be executed when it's called. I need callback to point to the function call in my parent method: `< ChildComponent callback = { myCallbackMethod } />`. I need myCallbackMethod to be executed when callback() is called. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: No. the typing I used does not say `nothing will be executed`, it says `callback is of type a function, which is called with no arguments, and no return value is expected from it`. read here for more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html